# React Router doesn`t load external html files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redirect, react-router-v4

I am building a *React App* with react + react-router, but I have a problem about the redirections.

I have the next folder structure:

`...
    /public
      /index.html (react index)
      /tos/
        /terms.html
        /privacy.html
      ...
    /src
      index.js
      App.js
      ...`

And the `index.js`:

```
class App extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
                    <Route path="/settings" component={Settings}/>
                </Switch>
            </Router>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

The problem is when I want redirect to `/public/tos/terms.html` or `/public/tos/privacy.html`, sometimes (more frequently in chrome), I can not. The project render again the index, and show a blank page because the route `/public/tos/terms.html` or `/public/tos/privacy.html` is not declared in the Route Switch.

On the other hand, I have other "no-react" project in the same base_url, but listen in other port `www.my-project.com:4040/other` and I have configured it in the next route: `www.my-project.com/other`. But in this case, I have the same problem, when I redirect from my React-app to this route, react do no redirect and render again the `App.js` without components inside.

Somebody could tell me any way for redirect to other place in the same project but out of react?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem it´s not related with ReactRouter... RR works in Google Chrome as well as other browsers. Look if you have the registerServiceWorker in your app because that could be the redirection error just in Chrome. If you have it and don´t use in other things just delete it.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Yes!! it is. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

If your trying to reach valid url  `/public/tos/terms.html` you must have component to take care of the url :

```
<Route  path="/public/tos/terms" component={/*Component to render*\ }/>
```

So it will be like :

```
        <Router>
          <div>
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/settings" component={Settings}/>
                <Route  path="/public/tos/terms" component={/*Component to render*\ }/>
                <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
            </Switch>
          </div>
        </Router>
```

If you are looking for how you can include your external files as a components inside your reactjs then one of the ways is , sending get request using [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) and then you can use it as [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) ,

```
function getExternalFile(fileName) {
   const request = axios.get('/myAPI/getExternalFile/' + fileName).then(
    respone =>
     {this.setState({externalFile: response})}); }

function MyComponent() {
  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={getHTMLFile()} />;
}
```

Comment: Hi Aaqib, thank you very much for your response, but It is not valid for me. I need to load the .html file, not render one React-component. I 'd want something like redirect to www.google.com but the "site" is in my project.

Answer (score 0):

What does "Redirect" mean in your app context?

If you want to simply Link from your footer for example to those static pages, use simple HTML anchor / link tags instead of React Router `Link` component.

For example:

```
const Footer = () => 
 <div>
   <a href='/tos/terms.html'>Terms and Conditions</a>
   <Link to='/login'>Sign in</Link>
 </div>
```

The first link will be handled by the browser and should work fine. The second one will be handled by React Router and should match a Route in your route configuration.

If you want to really `redirect`, like in user visits url A but I want it to finally land on url B, then show more code. ;)

Comment: Hi CharlieBrown, thank you very much for your answer. But it doesn't work for me. When I am saying redirect, I want to say the same thing that you are explaining in your answer. I want put a link that send you to /tos/terms.html and load the terms.html file. The problem about your answer is that I still have the same problem. I click in the <Link/> or <a href.../> element and index is loaded again without content, because the route is not defined in the <Switch/> component.

Comment: Hi Raul, it doesn't make too much sense. You're saying you can't basically use a normal `a href` tag for example to link to Google or prompt for an email with `href=mailto:xxxx` because React Router is handling everything? It seems to be that the problem is elsewhere. You could produce a small code example and we can work it out from that.

Comment: No, React router handling all "same-domain elements". For example: "/tos/terms.html" or "www.mydomain.com/tos/terms.html". I'll try to show more code in my next edition, but I don't know how much I can show. Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: To confirm, the `<a href='/tos/terms.html'>Terms and Conditions</a>` (@CharlieBrown 's) solution works in my project